# DId Quicktime 7.6.5 Windows fix QT for Java? Best video for JavaFX?

Tags: java, video, ffmpeg, javafx, quicktime

Greetings,

I have read that QuickTime for Java is esentially broken on both Windows 7 and Snow Leopard. I can't tell how broken -- doesn't *seem* broken, but could just be my setup. I'm trying to determine whether this is a good technology stack, or if I should look elsewhere.

Objective: I want to build a specialized desktop video player and annotation program for both Mac and Windows (and Linux if possible). I think I want to use JavaFX (JavaFX as a Flash/Flex alternative that can use all Java libs and can build a decent UI.) I need to use something like QuickTime vs. Flash video as I need frame-accurate playback and wide codec support. I'd prefer to code in a relatively high-level language (not C++).

Thanks, 
Cameron

Answer (score 1):

Apple seems to have abandon QT for Java.  Wikipedia's [**QuickTime for Java**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QuickTime_for_Java) page seems to sum it up well.  A select quote:

> Currently most of QTJ is broken on
>   recent windows-running computers.
>   Windows machines that use the
>   no-execute (NX) page-protection
>   security feature of recent CPUs cannot
>   run even the demos without changing
>   the configuration. This can be easily
>   verified by a developer via a test-run
>   of one of the demos coming with QTJ.
>   An "execution protection violation" is
>   reported and the program is aborted by
>   Windows. This renders QTJ unsuitable
>   for end-user application development
>   due to the necessary complicated
>   configuration of the NX feature.

So, not good.

> Following the 2003 release of QTJ 6.1,
>   Apple has made few updates to QTJ,
>   mostly fixing bugs. Notably, QuickTime
>   7 was the first version of QuickTime
>   not to be accompanied or followed by a
>   QTJ release that wrapped the new
>   native API's. QuickTime 7's new API's,
>   such as those for working with
>   metadata and with frame-reordering
>   codecs, are not available to QTJ
>   programmers. Apple has also not
>   offered new classes to provide the
>   capture preview functionality that was
>   present in versions of QTJ prior to
>   6.1. Indeed, QTJ is dependent on some native API's that Apple no longer
>   recommends, most notably QuickDraw.

And probably not going to look good.  Ever.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [Xuggler](http://www.xuggle.com/xuggler)?  It should work for you.